# Logic of getting a full-house of cards.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Although I understand the correct solution of finding the total number of full houses in a 52-deck of cards (finding the number of ways of selecting the first value and then finding the amount of ways you can select three cards out of four, etc...), I am unable to see where my approach is faulty.

Approach:
Let's start with the set of 3 cards.
Since you have 13 values to choose from, there are 13 choices to make. To get the second card, you only can chose from 3 remaining. To get the third, 2 remaining. And so the amount of ways to get a set of 3 is

13*3*2 = 78

Similarly, to get 2 cards out of the rest, you choose 12 out of the 13 values remaining. The second card can be chosen out of the three remaining.
The amount of ways to choose 2 cards out of the rest is:

12 *3 = 36

So the amount of full houses is 78 * 36 = 2808.

Where did my logic go wrong?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

A proper calculation is that you have $13$ ways to choose the three of a kind, $4$ ways to choose which three of that rank you have, $12$ ways to choose the rank of the pair, and ${4 \choose 2}=6$ ways to choose the two cards of the pair.  Multiplying gives $3744$ hands.

Your approach has several errors.  You have $52$ choices for the first card, as we consider different suits to be different.  You then overcount because you can choose the suits of the three of a kind in six orders.  You undercount because you ask that we draw the three of a kind first, while it could be mixed with the pair.  The pair could be drawn in either order.

Comment: I don't understand the part about having 52 choices even though I want 13 (or 12) in my erroneous solution. I understand the other two points. Thank you.

Comment: You need to be consistent with distinguishing suits.  When you multiply by 3 and 2 in the triplet, those are distinguished suits, so the first card has to be distinguished, too.  Then you are counting orders of drawing as distinct, so should divide by $3!=6$.  That gets you back to the correct $52$ sets of triplets.